# Drupal - Edit Views Selective Filters module to rename the option tag

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Actually, I try to make a filter criteria who list the available "structures" in my view. I'm using the Views Selective Filter module who does what I want. But in that list, that show the id of my structure and not the name. (I can't show you with an image, actually)

I want that my "structures" name replaces the id in my list (but not the value).

If you have any idea, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I have edited the Views Selective Filter module to allow him to detect and load my structure name.

After that, I just have to change the text of my option before that the id has assigned in.